# Weighted sum using multiple pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 pandas series which I want to make a weighted sum.

Basically i want to sum all of the elements in p,r,y and do the following operation

(1/n) * ((r * y) / p) where n is the number of elements

```
p = pd.Series(np.random.random(5)) 
r = pd.Series([1,0,0,1,0]) 
y = pd.Series([1,0,0,0,1])
```

How can I do this in a clean way?

I did it like so?

```
(1/len(r))((r.sum() * y.sum()) / p.sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of `lambda` for sum to make the code cleaner:

```
s = lambda x: x.sum()
(s(r)*s(y)/s(p))/len(r)
```

---

```
N = 5
p = pd.Series(np.random.random(N)) 
r = pd.Series([1,0,0,1,0]) 
y = pd.Series([1,0,0,0,1])
```

---

```
(s(r)*s(y)/s(p)) /N
```